# Angular: Creating plugins for 3rd party packages (libraries)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-module, angular-library

I created **Angular Library** ([ngx-wig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-wig)) and I would like to provide an ability to extend its functionality by using **plugins**.

What would be the best place to declare plugin in Angular? (*may be something like `myLibModule.forRoot(..)`*) and what type of instance should be plugin itself?

I [solved same issue](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngWig/tree/master/src/javascript/app/plugins) for **AngularJs** just by adding module for each plugin in which I register plugin by using [configProvider](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngWig/blob/master/src/javascript/app/plugins/clear-styles.ngWig.js#L2) of main module. Don't really like this solution because plugin registers itself, but it should be responsibility of applications where library is used.

**UPDATE**: related issue is opened on github [here](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-wig/issues/18).

Comment: It seems a little bit unclear. Do you want to provide an API like service?

Comment: it depends on plugin. some of them could extend toolbar with new button

Comment: Good question. I was facing a similar problem in a modular music production system, and the solution was that a "surface part" of each plugin must adhere to an interface which defines the _plugin assembly_, e.g. key-metadata about the plugin, such as name, key-classes, etc., and then the inner parts of the plugin itself work through decorator-hooks placed on methods (such as `@nodeDidActivate`, `@nodeStateDidChange`, etc.). This system uses React as its UI-layer, but it shouldn't be that different in ng.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can provide users to use component as a plug-in. This component has to extends you abstract base plugin component.

For example `clear-styles` plugin could look like

```
@Component({
  selector: `nw-clear-styles-button`,
  template: `
    <button (click)="clearStyles($event)" 
        [disabled]="editMode || disabled" 
        class="nw-button clear-styles" title="Clear Styles">
      Clear Styles
    </button>`
})
export class NwClearStylesButtonComponent extends Ng2WigPluginComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  clearStyles() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = this.content;
    this.contentChange.emit(div.textContent);
  }
}
```

`format` plugin

```
@Component({
  selector: `nw-formats-button`,
  template: `
    <select class="nw-select"
            [(ngModel)]="format"
            (ngModelChange)="execCommand('formatblock', format.value)"
            [disabled]="editMode || disabled">
      <option *ngFor="let format of formats" [ngValue]="format">{{ format.name }}</option>
    </select>
  `
})
export class NwFormatButtonComponent extends Ng2WigPluginComponent {
  formats = [
    {name: 'Normal text', value: '<p>'},
    {name: 'Header 1', value: '<h1>'},
    {name: 'Header 2', value: '<h2>'},
    {name: 'Header 3', value: '<h3>'}
  ];

  format = this.formats[0];

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

where `Ng2WigPluginComponent` is abstract base class provided by your library:

```
export abstract class Ng2WigPluginComponent {
  execCommand: Function;
  editMode: boolean;
  content: string;

  editModelChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  contentChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

So users can easily use declared in base class properties.

To register such plugins we can use mentioned by you `forRoot` method. For that you need to

**1)** configure you library module like follows:

**ng2wig.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
 ...
})
export class Ng2WigModule {
  static forRoot(entryComponents: CustomButton[]) {
    return {
      ngModule: Ng2WigModule,
      providers: [
        Ng2WigToolbarService,
        {provide: NG_WIG_CUSTOM_BUTTONS, useValue: entryComponents},
        {provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, multi: true, useValue: entryComponents},
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

where

- `NG_WIG_CUSTOM_BUTTONS` is your global library token to recognize provided plugins inside library

**ng2wig-toolbar.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class Ng2WigToolbarService {
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(NG_WIG_CUSTOM_BUTTONS) customButtons: CustomButton[]) {
    if (customButtons) {
      customButtons.forEach(plugin => this.addCustomButton(plugin.pluginName, plugin.component));
    }
  }
```

- `ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS` is angular global token to be able to load plugins dynamically

**2)** Declare `NwClearStylesButtonComponent` in declarations array of your `AppModule` module

**3)** Pass it to the `Ng2WigModule.forRoot` method

```
Ng2WigModule.forRoot([
   { pluginName: 'clear-styles', component: NwClearStylesButtonComponent },
   { pluginName: 'format', component: NwFormatButtonComponent }
])
```

And then main you task will be to dynamically generate your component by using `ComponentFactoryResolver` and `ViewContainerRef` (see `ng2wig-plugin.directive.ts` in plunker below)

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1MKYvgCzbMxZoVB1zhTs?p=preview)**

Comment: thank you, your answer is great! I have not provided bounty before to motivate others to share their answers